# Lectura de paquetes desde un servidor con sockets en Java

Tags: java, socket, tcp, redes, stream

Estoy desarrollando un programa de lectura de paquetes enviados por equipos a un servidor que tiene el puerto *7779* habilitado para recibir estos datos. Para esto utilizo sockets de *Java*.

El problema que tengo es que me abre el puerto, lee la información, pero después de un momento deja de recibir la misma. Aparentemente queda colgado, sé que siguen llegando datos porque lo compruebo con *tcpflow*.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    iniciarArchivoLog();
    iniciarConexionBaseDatos();

    procesarTramas();
}
private static void procesarTramas(){
    char caracter;
    byte[] bytes;
    InputStream stream = null;
    int bytesLeidos;
    Integer puerto;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    String hexadecimal, cadena = "";

    puerto = Integer.valueOf(obtenerPropiedad("socket.port"));

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        stream = socket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    bytesLeidos = 0;
    bytes = new byte[1];            

    while(true){
        try {
            bytesLeidos = stream.read();

            consolaLogger.info(String.valueOf(bytesLeidos));
            caracter = convertirEnteroACaracter(bytesLeidos);
            cadena += String.valueOf(caracter);
            if(caracter == '@'){
                consolaLogger.info(cadena);
                cadena = "@";
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
private static char convertirEnteroACaracter(int valor){
    char caracter;

    caracter = (char) valor;

    return caracter;
}
```

Utilizo el método `read()` para leer el entero desde el `stream`, y luego lo convierto a carácter para imprimirlo, después de algunas impresiones, ya no imprime más.

Answer (score 1):

Tu declaraste `bytes` como arreglo de byte y usas `bytesLeidos`, pero en tu código usas otra manera de leer datos de un stream. Me parece que usaste código de ejemplo o especificaciónes de una tarea y no lo aplicaste bien. Si queres trabajar con bytesLeidos deberías hacer algo así:

```
bytes = new byte[1024]    

while(bytesLeidos!=-1){
        bytes = new byte[stream.available()];
        bytesLeidos = stream.read(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i<bytesLeidos;i++){
             // has lo que quieras con bytes[i]
        }
}
// si bytesLeidos == -1, el InputStream llegó a su fin
```